# Can't import data from files into one line

Tags: python

I'm currently making this program that was given to me by my school and it's to write your own name in ASCII text art but that was just copying and pasting. I am trying to make it so the user enters an input and there their name is output. My program currently works except it doesnt stay on one line.

My code:

```
name = input("What is your name: ")

splitname = list(name)

for i in range(len(splitname)):
    f=open(splitname[i] + ".txt","r")
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

And this is what it outputs:
[image: output]

I would like to get it all onto one line if possible, how would I do so?

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify that you want all the letters printed in one line.

Comment: Is the question: how to print multiline text inputs onto one line in the python console?

Comment: @tda did you even look at the output he provided? That is clearly not what he wants.

Comment: Yes I did. He is reading the contents of a file with ascii text art and each is a character that is multi-line. He then wants to print each 'character' next to each other rather than one on top of the other as per the image. Your solution addresses the question I've asked so what's your problem? So for pedantry, the question will be: how to print multiline text inputs next to each other in the python console output.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a bit more complicated because you have to print out line by line, but you already need all the contents of the 'letter' files.

The solution would be to read the first line of the first letter, then concatenate this string with the first line of the next letter and so on. Then do the same for the second line until you printed all lines.

I will not provide a complete solution, but I can help to fix your code. To start you have to only read one line of the letter file. You can do this with `f.readline()` instead of `f.read()` each consecutive call of this function will read the next line in this file, if the handle is still open.

Answer (score 1):

To print the ASCII letters one next to the other, you have to split the letter into multiple lines and concatenate all the corresponding lines. 
Assuming your ASCII text is made of 8 lines:

```
name = input("What is your name: ")

splitname = list(name)

# Put the right number of lines of the ASCII letter
letter_height = 8

# This will contain the new lines 
# obtained concatenating the lines
# of the single letters
complete_lines = [""] * letter_height

for i in range(len(splitname)):
    f = open(splitname[i] + ".txt","r")
    contents = f.read()

    # Split the letter in lines
    lines = contents.splitlines()

    # Concatenate the lines
    for j in range(letter_height):
         complete_lines[j] = complete_lines[j] + " " + lines[j]

# Print all the lines
for j in range(letter_height):
    print(complete_lines[j])
```